# http patch request with urlencoded body

Tags: http, go, dockerhub

I would like to update my repository to docker hub via the provided API. I wrote a small program in Go that reads the content of a README.md file and sets the content as a description of the repository.

The program queries a JWT token using the login credentials of the given parms. The JWT token is then attached to the patch request for authentication. For the HTTP patch request I get the status code 200, but the description of the repository is not updated.

Here is an excerpt of the function:

```golang
data := url.Values{}
data.Set("full_description", repository.FullDescription)

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPatch, patchURL.String(), strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
if err != nil {
  return nil, fmt.Errorf("Can not create request to update readme: %v", err)
}
req.Header.Add("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("JWT %v", token.Token))
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

The complete function is provided on my [repository](https://git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/dhd/src/branch/master/pkg/hub/hub.go#L98).

After some time of searching I found a similar project that sends the request via curl. The flag --urlencode of curl is used. Without this flag the description will not be updated.

```sh
# Send a PATCH request to update the description of the repository
echo "Sending PATCH request"
REPO_URL="https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/${DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY}/"
RESPONSE_CODE=$(curl -s --write-out %{response_code} --output /dev/null -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" -X PATCH --data-urlencode full_description@${README_FILEPATH} ${REPO_URL})
echo "Received response code: $RESPONSE_CODE"
```

The complete source code of the project is hosted on [github](https://github.com/peter-evans/dockerhub-description/blob/master/entrypoint.sh)

Now I ask myself the question, how do I encode the content of the request so that the patch request is successfully accepted by the API?

Answer (score 1):

The curl request you mentioned is using a Patch request, you're using a Post request. Try http.MethodPatch instead.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the method back on patch because of all the testing. Same issue

Comment: You might try setting to Content-Length as well.

Comment: I have set the Content-Length, but it remains the same behavior. https://git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/dhd/src/branch/master/pkg/hub/hub.go#L126

Comment: If I was troubleshooting this, I'd printf the request, figure out how curl writes the request (would curl -v help?), and try to see if there's a mismatch.

Comment: It seems to be the content encoding. However, I don't know how to remove the encoding that golang automatically adds - diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/XcRRgtnM

Comment: It appears like default transport adds that. You might want to try the request with a client that has a `Transport` with `DisableCompression` set to true.